# Intercept console errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, console, syntax-error, try-catch

I'm trying to intercept console syntax errors with different methods in other posts but what I intercept and what is actually written in the console is different. I'm using the following methods for intercepting errors:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
   alert("onerror:"+message);
}

console.log=myconsole;
console.error=myconsole;

function myconsole(msg){
alert("console:"+msg);
}
```

The script with errors is being read dynamically after the page is loaded

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "script.js";
document.body.append(s);
```

script.js has one line `x=y;` 
In the console it says

> ReferenceError: y is not defined.

But in the alerts it says,

> "Script Error.";

I tried other methods such as try catch in other posts but I get the same result. How do I intercept the same syntax errors that are being sent to the console?

Comment: I don't think you can. The console is a debugging tool, there's no reason you could access it from inside the web page. IIRC, not be able to access any details about failed scripts is also a security feature. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: A user submits a dynamically generated script which will run on a web page. The script errors normally show up in the console. I want them to show up on the web page.

Comment: You might catch syntax errors by using a js parser (babylon, acorn, etc), probably the one that also does syntax highlighting in the submission form. You can catch runtime errors by wrapping the entire script in `try`/`catch` (unless it's asynchronous, of course)